# How to create certificate request with "not after" parameter for Db2 SSL/TLS?

Tags: db2, db2-luw, ssl

I have configured Db2 v11.5.7.0 on Linux/x64 to use SSL/TLS protocol and Db2 client can successfully connect to Db2 server using SSL/TLS. Now I would like to test certificate renewal. I need to create certificate request and then sign it with company CA with limitation of "not after" some date. I would like to set only few days certificate validity, so on my testing system I can test what happens when certificate expires.

I am using gsk8capicmd_64 to create certificate request. I checked [official documentation](https://manualzz.com/doc/24256533/gskcapicmd-users-guide), but can't figure it out. When renewing certificate request how to specify that certificate is not valid after specific date?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a database administration question, but

```
gsk8capicmd -cert -sign ... -expire 3
```